# Turn off ping probe for openvpn

Tags: openvpn, ping

I have got a VPS with *OpenVPN* server and a client. The problem is, that it is not possible to ping my IP address (where the client is located) from the VPS because of IPS restrictions, and therefore *OpenVPN* keeps disconnecting me, because of the option `keepalive 10 120` that keeps failing.

What should I write in `server.conf` in order to turn the ping probe off?

Comment: `keepalive` does not send pings. So that is not why the connection is failing.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/925755

Comment: Yes, exactly. So you need to look elsewhere for the problem.

Comment: I'm with @MichaelHampton on this: what OpenVPN calls "pings" refers to the special probe packets it sends *inside the logical connection it manages;* they aren't "ICMP echo request" packets—colloquially called "pings".

Comment: As to the exact problem, it's more involved: if the keepalive mechanism tears your session down, it means your link has problems. I mean, keepalives detect the link is broken; if you disable keepalives, the link won't magically "unbreak". Now there can be two types of problems: the link is slow or it's succeptible for mass packet outages. If the link is slow, try increasing keepalive's timeouts, and the number of unacknowledged packets to consider the link to be dead.

Comment: If the link is known to become corrupt from time to time, it actually may help to make the keepalive params more "aggressive" so that the link is attempted to be reestablished as soon as possible when it's considered dead. That is, only experimentation may help in this case, alas.

Comment: You might also try to research whether there's a problem with P-MTU on your link. Read up on `--tun-mtu`, `--fragment`, `--fix-mss` etc in [the manual](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage) (and search the internets for more hints on those).

Comment: And it could also be your IPS is detecting the VPN traffic and blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, why was it happening.
https://forums.untangle.com/networking/16138-openvpn-clients-disconnecting-every-hour.html - ip address on the client side is renewed each hour and therefore connection is reseting. 
The messages in logs don't really give any hint, they only indicate a time out and a tls-handshake error.

So, the solution is simple - don't use a bridged interface with you virtual machine.